# Where is Mono.Data.Sqlite source code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm going through some problems with SQLite on Linux and I'd like to inspect Mono.Data.Sqlite source code, but it seems Mono's page on SQLite is outdated and does not point to Mono.Data.Sqlite code repository.

I've done my homework searching it at Google but with no success.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've found something but I don't think it is what I'm looking for: https://github.com/mattleibow/Mono.Data.Sqlite. Its author does not appear on Mono's doc (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a class library within the Mono project : https://github.com/mono/mono

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite

[image]